# Need to Open Port 1111 in unix server

Tags: openconnect

I have a request to open port 1111.

Below is the output i get for netstat -nptl

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3873                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39334               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57158               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5001                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59338               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1098                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1099                0.0.0.0:*                                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8083                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3035                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4444                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4445                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4446                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:959                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::6688                     :::*                        LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::6689                     :::*                        LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::8898                     :::*                        LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::8899                     :::*                        LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::24071                    :::*                        LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::11111                    :::*                        LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::3434                     :::*                        LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      -
```

How can I open the port?

Below is the output of iptables

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: The service is indeed listening, however when people ask me to "open" a port, they are talking about firewall rules. Please post the output of `iptables -L -n`

Comment: All seems ok...time to talk with the network team?

Comment: Okay @RuiFRibeiro ..... Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

This should be a comment, but I can't do that on unix...

Do note that in your question you mention port 1111, but there is a service on port 111 for IPV4 and a service listening on port 11111 for IPV6. So I do not agree that there is a service listening on the port you mentioned like Rui F ribeiro said. Is this mixup where it goes wrong?

Comment: nah, 1111/TCP is listening both in IPv4 and IPv6, and 111/TCP is for the portmap(per) service.

Comment: Where in that list do you see a service listening on port 1111?

Comment: Good point. I saw 11111 and my mistake. ;) A typo on the OP part?

Comment: maybe not. 1111/tcp is monit, no use to open it in any firewall as it is not running. My fault too. Here when we receive requests as open this and that port, we *always* ask for more clarifications.